# Kivy buildozer: how to deploy to specific android device

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I have multiple devices (both AVDs and hardware) connected to my PC, but I want to deploy to a specific device with `buildozer`. How can I do that if disconnecting other devices is not an option?

Comment: Either you can pass the arguments to adb through buildozer, in which case you probably need to look at the code to see how, or you can't, in which case you can just run adb yourself with the arguments you want.

Answer (score 0):

Buildozer installs to android via adb. So you have to check the documentation of adb and check how it is modified in the buildozer startup script.

http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/install-apk-on-device-adb/
and https://pypi.org/project/buildozer/
Think the command will be like

```
buildozer android deploy adb --s <DEVICE_NAME>
```

Comment: With this command, it deploys to all connected devices regardless to DEVICE_NAME. Buildozer documentation is silent on this, at least I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As on JAN 18 2020:

It seems like `buildozer 1.0.1-dev0` does not have enough flexibility to accomplish this task. Commands like `buildozer android deploy adb -s <DEVICE_ID>` just ignore DEVICE_ID and install `apk` on all available devices.
  There is a handy `buildozer serve` command, but that is slow and requires to manually answer to all security dialogs.

Using `adb` directly is a fair option, e.g.:

```
adb -s DEVICE_ID install -r your.apk
```

But if there are a lot of devices (armv7 and x86), it'd be a chore to type this every time.  So I ended up with a script that is placed in the project directory:

```
import sys
import subprocess

# TODO: edit your custom settings
ADB_EXE = "/home/your_username/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb"
APK_X86 = "/path/to/apk/x86/bin/your_project__x86-0.1-x86-debug.apk"
APK_ARMV7 = "/path/to/apk/armv7/bin/your_project__armeabi-v7a-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk"

DEVICES = {
    # DEVICE_PSEUDO_NAME: ("DEVICE_ID", "PATH_TO_APK")
    "pixtab": ("emulator-5554", APK_X86),
    "pix": ("emulator-5556", APK_X86),
    "nexus4": ("004a900e1b268111", APK_ARMV7),
    "nomi": ("SSI1216C111031288", APK_ARMV7),
}


def run():
    global ADB_EXE
    global DEVICES
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("Please, specify device.")
        return
    if sys.argv[1] == "list":
        # print all available android devices
        res = subprocess.check_output([ADB_EXE, "devices"])
        for line in res.splitlines():
            print(line)
        return

    dev_name = sys.argv[1]
    print(f"Selected device: {dev_name}")
    if dev_name not in DEVICES:
        print(f"Device is not in the list, skipping.")
        return

    dev_id, apk = DEVICES[dev_name]
    # "-r" means force install
    res = subprocess.check_output([ADB_EXE, "-s", dev_id, "install", "-r", apk])
    for line in res.splitlines():
        print(line)

    print(f"-- Deployment into {dev_id} complete.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

To list all devices:

```
python3 dp.py list
```

To deploy specific `apk` to specific device:

```
python3 dp.py YOUR_DEVICE_PSEUDO_NAME
```